# Ubuntu XFCE LightDM - login screen background mix-up on multiple monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, xfce, lightdm, desktop-background

I'm running UbuntuStudio 19.10 with XFCE and two monitors.

```
$ cat /etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf

[greeter]
background = /home/ganga/Google Drive/Photos/Wallpaper/Subway.jpg
font-name = DejaVu Sans 14
default-user-image = /home/ganga/Google Drive/Photos/Ganga Kelly.jpg

[monitor: HDMI-1]
background = /home/ganga/Google Drive/Photos/Wallpaper/Subway.jpg

[monitor: HDMI-2]
background = /home/ganga/Google Drive/Photos/Wallpaper/Subway.jpg
```

Yet when I boot up, *both* monitors momentarily flash `Subway.jpg` and switch to show the image that was set as the *wallpaper* on HDMI-1 - i.e., the `greybird.svg` file in:

`<property name="last-image" 
    type="string" 
    value="/usr/share/backgrounds/greybird.svg"/>`

entry from `/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-desktop.xml`.

Even when I make the desktop on HDMI as 'None' for a solid colour it still picks up the image that *previously* set as the wallpaper - `greybird.svg`.

I've searched everywhere in `/etc`, `/usr/share` and `~/.config` for stray references to `greybird.svg`. I've removed everything in `/tmp`. And even removed the `last-image` entry from `xfce4-desktop.xml`, before a reboot. But no. My `greeter` settings appear briefly before the previous wallpaper takes over both monitors.

PS: the other settings in `greeter`, such as `default-user-image` are just fine.

Has anyone had the same issue and found a workaround? Thanks.

Comment: Grrr....user error. Adding `user-background=false` to `/etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf` solved the issue.